# site_url is not honoring scheme

Tags: functions, site-url

I'm using site_url() for my href for anchors. I want to control what when I send the user to a secure page or non secure page. I thought I could do that with site_url('/foo', 'http') and site_url('/bar', 'https') but the scheme is not changing. If I'm on a secure page and site_url('/foo', 'http') is set, the clicked page is still secure instead of non-secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is original link?

```
var_dump( get_option('siteurl') );
```

If I am interpreting code right then for `http` protocol argument action is to **not change** the link. So if you have set up URL to be secure by default then function doesn't override that.

Comment: Yeah at this point in the site the site url is https. I'm guessing it changes the is_SSL() return.